# ¿Como no permitir consultar un web service si no envió el token de autorización, laravel, JWTAuth?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jwt

Buen día.

Actualmente en laravel utilizo la libreria JWTAuth para generar token de autorización, con el siguiente metodo:

```
public function userAuth(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('usuario','password');
        $token = null;

        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Credenciales invalidas']);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $ex) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Algo salio mal'],500);
        }
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
        return response()->json(compact('token','user'));
    }
```

Cuando ingreso las credenciales correctamente devuelve lo siguiente:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4L3BtdC9iYWNrZW5kL3B1YmxpYy93cy9hdXRlbnRpY2FjaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM3NjgzMDczLCJleHAiOjE1Mzc2ODY2NzMsIm5iZiI6MTUzNzY4MzA3MywianRpIjoiQ2JZdU05Q0ZjSWROaDBiVSJ9.Es8HJJi3UF17dQcfHRHvogct4_z1Ka73LyQJFohx28k",
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Administrador",
        "apellido": "Administrador",
        "usuario": "Admin",
        "idtipousuario": 1,
        "correo": "admin@gmail.com",
        "telefono": 54807090,
        "estado": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-08-19 00:41:07",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-29 04:33:52",
    }
}
```

El token y la informacion del usuario logeado.
Como puedo utilizar ese token que me genero como acceso a consultar los otros web services que tengo realizados, por ejemplo tengo la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ws', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    Route::resource('usuarios','UsuariosController');
});
```

y en el navegador simplemente ingreso a `http://localhost:808/proyectolaravel/public/ws/usuarios`
lo cual me muestra la siguiente informacion, dicha informacion solamente es un ejemplo, pues me devuelve mas informacion:

```
{"message":"Consulta Exitosa",
    "result":true,
    "records":[
    {
    "id":1,
    "nombre":"Usuario prueba",
    "apellido":"Prueba",
    "usuario":"prueba",
    }]}
```

Entonces existen ciertos metodos que debo validar que solamente pueden ser consultados si se envia el token de autorizacion, caso contrario un mensaje de que necesita acceso.

Consulto lo anterior para posteriormente utilizarlo en una petición desde jquery de la siguiente forma y de igual forma en el navegador no pueda acceder cualquier usuario:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:808/proyectolaravel/public/ws/usuarios`, {
 headers: {
        Authorization: token
    }
})
```

Donde la variable `token` ya ha almacenado el token generado por el servidor.

Este es el metodo donde consulto el registro de usuarios

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $header  = $request->header('Authorization');
            if ($header!="") {
               if (JWTAuth::authenticate($header)) {
                    $registros  = Usuarios::all();
                    $statusCode = 200;
                    $this->records = $registros;
                    $this->message = "Consulta Exitosa";
                    $this->result  = true;      
               }
               else{
                    $statusCode = 200;
                    $this->records = [];
                    $this->message = "Token incorrecto";
                    $this->result  = true;    
               }
            }
            else{
                $statusCode = 200;
                $this->records = [];
                $this->message = "Debe estar autenticado para tener acceso al metodo";
                $this->result  = true;   
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $statusCode = 404;
            $this->message = "No existen registros";
            $this->result  = false;
        }
        finally{
            $response = [
                'message' => $this->message,
                'result'  => $this->result,
                'records' => $this->records
            ];
                return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el controlador puedes definir en el constructor los métodos con los que quieres que se valide usando except para excluir metodos que no necesitan o only para definir los que necesitan según sea conveniente, si no lo logra retornara el json de error que definiste ['error'=>'Credenciales invalidas'.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['metodo']]);
}
```

o puedes hacerlo en el metodo para controlar las credenciales de otra forma, yo lo use por que necesitaba usar el método tanto para usuarios logeados o no, y si era logeado necesitaba su información, con el metodo contructor no me servia por que necesitaba pasar si el token para ejecutar el método.

```
$header = $request->header('Authorization');
if($header!=""){
    if(JWTAuth::authenticate($header)){
      //si se logra autenticar
    }else{
      //si no lo logra
    }
}else{//si ni paso el header}
```

Comment: Buena noche estimado, tengo la siguiente duda con el if JWTAuth.authenticate, resulta que cuando envio el token completo en header por postman, efectivamente me devuelve los registros, pero si por ejemplo en el header ingreso Authorization = cualquierotrotexto, deberia enviarme al else //si no lo logra. pero me envia al catch.